# LXC: How can I mount a drive/directory without restarting the container?

Tags: mount, lxc

If I configure LXC's fstab and restart, there's no problem with the mount, but do I have to restart?

Comment: `mount -a` should do that (reload fstab).

Comment: I suppose by ”LXC's fstab“ you mean ”an LXC container's fstab“, no?

Answer (score -1):

No there is no need to restart anything. After adding the corresponding line in fstab, ust run:

```
mount /path/to/mount/point
```

Or if you want to mount everything in fstab, run:

```
mount -a
```

Comment: afaik this will not work for LXC containers, so it does not answer the question.